# Cookie not being reset in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I am new to cookies. I created a user login php class that uses a cookie to store a unique MD5 key to remember a user that has logged in. However, the cookie is not being reset when the user logs out. I created a function from code I found on stack overflow to clear the cookies on logout.

```
static public function clearCookies() 
{
    $past = time() - 3600;
    foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value )
    {
            $value = '';
        setcookie( $key, $value, $past );
        setcookie( $key, $value, $past, '/' );
    }
}
```

However, the cookie is still not being cleared.

This is the line of code that sets the cookie

```
setcookie("auth_key", $authKey, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
```

Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked.

I changed

```
setcookie("auth_key", $authKey, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
```

to

```
setcookie("auth_key", $authKey, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/');
```

It seems that the cookie was not being reset because the url it was being reset from was different than the url it was set in. After adding '/' it could be reset from the new url.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
static public function clearCookies() 
{
    $past = time() - 3600;
    foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value )
    {
            $value = '';
        setcookie( $key, $value, $past );
        setcookie( $key, $value, $past, '/' );
        unset($_COOKIE[$key]);
    }
}
```

You have to note that changed cookies are readable AFTER sending them to client (if you do not set them manually via $_COOKIE), so the next refresh.

Comment: How does `unset($_COOKIE[$key])` benefit the situation?

Comment: I got ahead of myself. Tried it on the live server it did not work.

Comment: @webbiedave: user doesn't have to reload the page in order to see changes in the rest of his code

Comment: @simpleengine: aren't you setting it back somewher?

Comment: Here is the solution that worked.

I changed

    setcookie("auth_key", $authKey, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);

to 

    setcookie("auth_key", $authKey, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/');

It seems that the cookie was not being reset because the url it was being reset from was different than the url it was set in. After adding '/' to setcookie() it could be reset from the new url.

Comment: @simpleengine: you've got solution for both cases in my/your code